# Выбор 10 записей имеющих наибольшее число совпадений параметра.

Tags: sql-server, sql

Есть таблица "пользователи": `id, name, city`.

Необходимо получить 10 городов, число пользователей в которых максимально.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select top 10 city 
from users
group by city
order by count(1) desc
```

Comment: Действительно, все просто. А прокомментируйте, пожалуйста, count(1). Если я правильно понял, чтобы подцепить ещё и кол-во, то необходимо писать: select top 10 city, count(1). Что значит 1?

Comment: @michael, правильно поняли. `1` обозначает, что мы каждой строке попавшей в выборку сопоставляем число `1`. `Group by` собирает эти строки в группы, a `count()` применяется уже к каждой группе. Таким образом мы считаем, сколько единичек (а значит и строчек) попало в каждую группу.

В данной ситуации само значение `1` не критично. Мы с тем же успехом могли написать `count(2)`, `count(id)` или `count(*)`, т.к. агрегатная функция `count` возвращает кол-во строк в подчиненном наборе строк.

Comment: PS. @michael, если ответ вам помог (не только этот), не забывайте отмечать его галочкой (слева от ответа) - у вас мало принятых ответов.